# How to create a relative symlink on a mac (i.e. not an "alias")

Tags: macos, filesystems, symlink

I can create a working symlink on a Mac in the terminal like this:

```
ln -s /absolute/path/foo.txt /absolute/path/elsewhere/bar.txt
```

However, this is absolute paths. I want this symlink to be shared in a GitHub repo. So it needs to be *relative*. But when I do the following it creates an *alias*, not a *symlink*, and aliases can't be rendered or edited in a text editor.

```
ln -s ./relative/path/foo.txt ./another/relative/path/bar.txt
```

It shows this when I try to preview it too:

[image]

How to get this to work? I think [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3028196) is similar question. But it doesn't have a clear answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Ask Different.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/160249/28726

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but my suggestion is "don't". Instead, have the build system create the link as necessary at build time.